# while opening terminal, i get this automatically -- Entering Ex mode. Type "visual" to go to Normal mode. :

Tags: command-line

I just update my ubuntu os from 18 to 20.4 , Every time I open a fresh terminal I get this error, I will also be sharing a screenshot.

**Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:**

I have to enter quit in a terminal once the terminal starts,is there any way of dealing with it once? [click for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3JVe.png)

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18, or other *snap* based *yy* release won't upgrade to a *yy.mm* or a *deb* based desktop or server release, so you were likely on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (server or desktop).  If you were on a *yy* or *snap* based release such as Ubuntu Core 18 I'd check for upgrade issues.  You likely have something added to `.bashrc` or a similar profile that runs a command you want to remove. However if you were on a *yy* release and switched to a *yy.mm* release I'd see that is your biggest concern as they are different.

Comment: thanks, it helped, in my bashrc fie something unwanted was written I deleted it.